# TreeNodeCheckChanged is not working in my ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, treeview

`TreeNodeCheckChanged` is not working in my ASP.Net application.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" ShowCheckBoxes="All" runat="server"                      
     OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="TreeView1_TreeNodeCheckChanged">
</asp:TreeView>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
   {
      TreeView(); //bind manually
   }
}
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you binding your `TreeView`?

I guess you are binding on every `Page_Load` (or `Page_Init`, whatever) regardless of `this.Page.IsPostback`

If you rebind your `TreeView` before the `EventHandler` is reached in the Asp.net Lifecycle, you will suppress all events that should be raised, e.g. your `OnTreeNodeCheckedChanged` event

Only bind upon

```
if(!this.Page.IsPostBack)
{
  // insert your initial binding of your treeview here
}
```

Upon postbacks you have to rebind after the desired event handlers have been executed

---

**Edit**:
You need to manually force a `PostBack`, because the `TreeView` won't fire a `Postback` changing the Checked property of the rendered checkboxes.

> Even though the `TreeNodeCheckChanged` 
>   event is fired on post back, changing
>   a check box does not cause a post
>   back.

[TreeView.TreeNodeCheckChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodecheckchanged.aspx)

Comment: No you didn't. There is no DataSourceID property assigned in the markup. That means if your TreeView displays something, you are manually assigning either the DataSourceID property or the DataSource property and call .DataBind(). Or you manually access the Nodes property and manipulate it. Otherwise your TreeView is empty and won't be able to fire the CheckedChanged Event, because there are no nodes

Comment: I bind it manually on the page load within if(!IsPostBack){}.But CheckedChanged event can't fire.